# How to create edge in OrientDB for thousands of vertex?

Tags: sql, orientdb

I have two classes, accountholder and Transactions in orientDB, AccountHolder has the person informations, transactions has the accHolderID from accountholder class and each accountholder have multiple transactions, to create edges do I have to one by one and create,

Is it possible to create by one query.

Example
AccontHolder class has properties AccID, Type, AcDate, AcCode and thousand data in it
transactions class has properties TrxID, TrDate, TrCode, Merchant, Amount, AccID and million data in it

I need to create Edges, say
AccID to their TrxID's
Merchant to AccID
Merchant to Type
likewise many edges, so I can traverse in graph

To Create the Edges, Do I have to go one by one, Or How can I create all?

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple edges in single query
Please refer orientdb documentation for [Create an edge of the class E between multiple vertices](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Edge.html#sql---create-edge). Where you can create one to many edges.